# Some elements missing / changed when trying to change from html to php

Tags: php, html

I'm asking for help for those who have experience in changing an html file to a php file. I've tried everything I know (and I'm not the smartest I admit) but I don't understand why the following is happening.

Currently: When viewing on mobile, the mobile menu button has gone, the toggle switch which changed prices from monthly to annually, tabs which displayed different content has gone. As a result:

- If there was a toggle, both the toggle results are displayed one above the other
- If there was a tab, each tab element is displayed underneath the other
- The mobile menu button has gone completely

**Background:**
I purchased an HTML template but it turns out the seller didn't want to help. I wanted to split and convert the page into a php page as I wanted a single header/footer file which I could import. As you will see (if you check the repo) the header.php and footer.php file is getting imported into the page php file.

I created the pages by first:

- Renaming the original html file to a php file
- Cut the header and footer and import them back into the page php file

That's all I have done. It seemed to work, however another check (after cache cleared) I noticed the issues.

The link to the site page im referring to is:

https://blueboxhosting.co.uk/products-cloud-hosting

But if you look at any of the pages, you'll see errors on all of them now where they're should have been controls (eg toggles, mobile menu, tabs etc)

I've created a snipped so you can view the code and HOPEFULLY spot where I've been a moron:

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/bbhostinguk/7e5qxp

Any help with this would be amazing as I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by running the HTML generated by PHP through a validator, e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

Your code has numerous stray tags which may or may not affect the rendering.

Another tip is to comment off everything and then uncomment section by section and check when things start to break.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I will try again and see if I can make it work, however i didn't think renaming to a .php file and the cutting the header part and importing the header (now a header.php file) would have broke it?

Comment: @Paul, splitting the file and rename should not have broken anything. However, if the code was working earlier, you broke something.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you're saying. I thought it must have been a cache version I had been viewing and when it cleared, that's when I noticed issues.